# Tk() Handling pagination with a button

Tags: python, tkinter

Guys I am creating an app,and need pagination in the shape of NEXT and PREVIOUS e.g

```
listt1 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12], [13,14,15], [16,17,18]]
list2=[]
next = ""
prev = ""
def show_list():
    if next == "clicked":
        for i in listt1[0 : 1]:
            show.insert(END, i)
            listt2.append(i)
            listt1.del(i)
    if prev == "clicked":
        for n in listt2[0 : 1]:
            show.insert(END, n)
def prev_btn():
    prev = 'clicked'
    show_list()
def next_btn():
    next = 'clicked'
    show_list()
btn1 = tk.Button(win, text='next',command=next_btn)
btn1.pack(side='left')
btn2 = tk.Button(win, text='prev',command=prev_btn)
btn2.pack=(side='left')
show = tk.Entry(win, width=6)
show.pack(side'bottom')

win = Tk()
win.title("clickers")
win.mainloop()

#OUTPUT  FOR BUTTON(NEXT) ON EACH CLICK SHOULD BE
 1,2,3 and 4,5,6
  7,8,9 and 10,11,12
 13,14,15 and 16,17,18

#OUTPUT FOR BUTTON(PREV) ON EACH CLICK SHOULD BE
7,8,9 and 10,11,12
1,2,3 and 4,5,6
```

I want it just the way it works on a website,please guys I know this is easy,and a basic  knowledge of handling a list and loop will do,this i do but can't seem to get around this one.

Guys also need help with this

(1) i need a working code for uploading an image into my database,retrieving and displaying and resizing this to a really small size

(2) can a tkinter app page be printed just like in a website, probably need a code for this too

(3 ) i won't mind a link to a really beautiful looking tkinter app video too,as making one myself looks a bit ugly

thank you all in advance guys

Comment: Provide what you have done so far. In its current state your question will get downvoted and closed.

Comment: The other questions you "also need help with" must be asked as separate questions.

Comment: For your third extra question: see [`ttk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html)

Comment: Your current code has several syntax errors, by the way – there's no way you could have run that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example based on your code that paginates through a list and shows the items in the Entry box.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import math

items = [str(n) for n in range(100)]

page = 0
per_page = 5
n_pages = math.ceil(len(items) / per_page)


def update_list():
    print(page)
    start_index = int(page * per_page)
    end_index = int((page + 1) * per_page)
    items_in_page = items[start_index:end_index]
    view_text = "Page %d/%d: %s" % (page + 1, n_pages, ", ".join(items_in_page))
    show.delete(0, tk.END)
    show.insert(0, view_text)


def change_page(delta):
    global page
    page = min(n_pages - 1, max(0, page + delta))
    update_list()


def prev_btn():
    change_page(-1)


def next_btn():
    change_page(+1)


win = tk.Tk()
win.title("clickers")
tk.Button(win, text="next", command=next_btn).pack()
tk.Button(win, text="prev", command=prev_btn).pack()
show = tk.Entry(win)
show.pack()
update_list()  # to initialize `show`
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks,this solves my problem,but the problem for me now is how to change this part of your code-> items = [str(n) for n in range(100)] from a loop of  numbers into a loop for a list, just like I have it in the variable listt1 in my question above,so that on click of next button it loops and display the first 5 list(not numbers) seperately until the end,and the other way around for prev button,I need it separate cos I want to deal with indexes of each 5 in each loop,thank man

Comment: Just replace that bit with just a list. `items = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "whatever..."]`

Comment: Well replace that part with this -> items = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12], [13,14,15], [16,17,18]], and the other part to this-> n_pages = math.ceil(len(items) / per_pages),only the last list enters into the entry widget and doesn't change on click of both buttons